# Chatter and Dashboard location on home page

Tags: chatter, home-page-component

Is it possible to put a ticker stream above the Chatter feed in the home page layout ? I've put the marquee coding into an HTML area and included that in the Wide Components to Show in the layout, but since it automatically puts the Dashboard below the Chatter the ticker is below the feed, which makes it less noticeable to the user if there is a long Chatter feed on their Home Page.

Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how much effort you have put in so far, but there is a pretty nice app for this.  Check out

[Improved Notice Board.](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005ueMvEAI)

I have played around with it in my sandbox.  You can check out a free trial.  Seems to be what you are looking for and it has some other cool features.  If you don't want to pay you can replicate what they are doing with a little effort.  Just injecting some javascript into the DOM.

For something like that I would just assume to by the app so they have to worry about maintaining rather than having to maintain it myself should SF have some HTNML changes.

Comment: Thanks @SF_Ninja - I'm looking into it. I'll try and see how much effort it's gonna take.

Comment: just fyi : I've done more research on this and according to what I've found it is not possible to make anything appear above the Feed in the Home tab. I've seen a bunch of different instances online where people are complaining about it, saying it's a flaw to the Home tab. One of the things some people have been been upset about is that they would like to put Tasks above Feeds because they feel their users want that first and foremost when going to their Home page. Even a VF page would get pushed below it.